# Problem with decimal for bep ICO

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a token in BEP¨20
How would i set the price of my token to 0.1 BUSD, would i convert ?

```
uint tokenPrice = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;  // 1 token= 0.1 BUSD
```

Is that right ?